# Python - Beautiful Soup. Why wont my scraping loop work?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the names, last stocks and last update from Nordnet.no with Python
I have made a function for this, but I only get the first result - not the rest.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.nordnet.no/market/stocks?selectedTab=prices&page=2'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('div', id='app')

#print(results.prettify())

stock_elems = results.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'c02352 c02354 md c02353'})


def finn():
    for elem in stock_elems:
        title_elem = elem.find('td', {'data-title': 'Navn'}) ## Navn
        company_elem = elem.find('td', {'data-title': 'Siste'}) ## Siste
        location_elem = elem.find('td', {'data-title': 'Tid'}) ## plassering
        if None in (title_elem, company_elem, location_elem):
            continue
        print(title_elem.text.strip())
        print(company_elem.text.strip())
        print(location_elem.text.strip())
        print()

finn()
```

Comment: The loop works as expected. Because your both `stock_elems` and `results` have length of 1. This means `find` statements finds only one item. Be sure that `find` and `find_all` are working as you expect from them.

Comment: You should also use some headers. Just for good practice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you aren't saving the results of your scraping anywhere...